# Get path element from URL using findText()

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Say you have the following paragraph in a Google Doc and you want to pull the element out of the url that relates to a car.

Some paragraph with some data in it has a url http://example.com/ford/some/other/data.html. There is also another link: http://example.com/ford/latest.html.

What I am looking for is pulling "ford" out of this paragraph so I can use it. And for the sake of simplicity I know the paragraph number, I will just call it "1" down below.

I have tried:

```
function getData() {
  var paragraphs = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  var element = paragraphs[1];
  var re = element.findText('http://example.com/([a-z])+/');
  var data = re.getElement().asText().getText();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

The problem is that `data` contains the entire paragraph text.

Also is there a way to capture and use the data from a capturing group, aka the content in the ()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal like below.

- You want to retrieve the value of `ford` from the values like `http://example.com/ford/latest.html` and `http://example.com/ford/some/other/data.html` using Google Apps Script.
- Those values are put in Google Document.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In your script, when `element.findText('http://example.com/([a-z])+/')` has a value, `re.getElement().asText().getText()` is the text of the paragraph. In this case, it is found that the text with the pattern by `element.findText()` is including in `element`. Using this, how about retrieving the values like `ford` from `re.getElement().asText().getText()`?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var data = re.getElement().asText().getText();
Logger.log(data);
```

To:

```
if (re) {
  var data = [...re.getElement().asText().getText().matchAll(/http:\/\/example\.com\/([\w\S]+?)\//g)];
  console.log(data.map(([,e]) => e));
} else {
  throw "Not match."
}
```

- When the paragraph has no values which maches to your regex, `re` is `null`. Please be careful.

#### Note:

- Please use the script with enabling V8.

#### Reference:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Answer (score 1):

As a supplementary to Tanaike's, this answer intends to show what could be done if you had to use the `findText()` method (like simultaneously changing element attributes, highlighting matched ranges, etc).

---

*The problem is "data" now is the entire paragraph*

Well, this is exactly due to the instructions provided:

1. Result of `getElement()` is the `Element` itself.
2. Result of `asText()` on the `Element` is `Text` instance.
3. Result of `getText()` on the `Text` is, to quote docs:

> the contents of the element as text string

---

*is there a way to capture and use the data*

With `findText()` it doesn't seem to be possible as per [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern) at the time of writing, to quote it for posterity:

> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

---

**What to do?**

When a match is found, `findText()` returns a `RangeElement` instance which has two methods of interest: `getStartOffset()` and `getEndOffsetInclusive()`. The return values of these methods point to character *indices* of the element's text content. Thus, the matched substring can be extracted via a `substring()` method (or via `slice()`).

You can use `from` parameter of the `findText()` method recursively to iterate over the match results to obtain all matching ranges.

```
/**
 * @summary pattern wrapper
 * @param {string} linkPattern
 * @param {RegExp} [infoPattern]
 */
const matchText = (linkPattern, infoPattern) => 

  /**
   * @summary finds links in text elements
   * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} elem
   * @param {string} [text]
   * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.RangeElement} [from]
   * @param {string[]} [matches]
   * @returns {string[][]}
   */ 
  (elem, text = elem.getText(), from, matches = []) => {

    const match = from ? 
      elem.findText(linkPattern, from) : 
      elem.findText(linkPattern);

    if(match) {
       const rangeStart = match.getStartOffset();
       const rangeEnd = match.getEndOffsetInclusive();

       const link = text.substring( rangeStart, rangeEnd + 1 );
       const [ full, ...groups ] = link.match( infoPattern );

       matches.push(groups);

       return matchText(linkPattern, infoPattern)(elem, text, match, matches);
    }

    return matches;
  }
```

Driver script for testing:

```
function findText() {
  const doc = getTestDoc(); //gets doc somehow, not provided here

  const body = doc.getBody();

  const par = body.appendParagraph("Some paragraph with some data in it https://example.com/ford/some/other/data.html.\nThere is another link also here https://example.com/ford/latest.html.");

  const pattern = 'http(?:s)*:\/\/(?:www\.)*example\.com\/\\w+';
  const targetPattern = /\/(\w+)$/;

  const results = matchText(pattern,targetPattern)(par);

  Logger.log(results); //[[ford], [ford]]
}
```

**Notes**

1. Curious observation: apparently, to pass tokens (`\w`,`\s`, etc) to the expression `string`, one has to *escape* the backslash (e.g. `\\w` will be parsed correctly).
2. Note that the solution above returns a `string[][]` to extract all capturing groups ()
3. The example code above is designed for the V8 runtime.

**References**

1. `getElement()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getElement())
2. `asText()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#astext)
3. `getText()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getText())
4. `findText()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern)
5. `getStartOffset()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getstartoffset)
6. `getEndOffsetInclusive()` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getendoffsetinclusive)
7. `substring()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) on MDN